# Atualização para PHP 7 ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

Após a atualização do PHP em meu servidor Ubuntu meu `phpinfo()` continua mostrando a versão anterior `5.5` mesmo quando executo `php -v` (retorna a versão 7.0).

Já tentei restart no apache e no `php7.0-fpm` e não funcionou.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760907/upgrade-to-16-04-php7-not-working-in-browser

Comment: Pelo que sei, o PHP só funciona corretamente nos Ubuntu 16.x. Essa é a tua versão?

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino 14.04

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino não, não, no Ubuntu 14 funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 5):

Primeiramente, é preciso dizer que, depois da atualização do  PPA, o PHP está sendo instalado como múltiplas versões. No meu caso, tenho instalado o PHP 5.6 e o PHP 7.0.

Provavelmente, você instalou o PHP novo, porém não ativou o `PHP 7.0` no Apache.

Você pode tentar fazer assim:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6

sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

Note que é necessário rodar `a2dismod` para desativar desabilitar o módulo com a versão anterior, e `a2enmod` para habilitar a versão `7`.

Após fazer essas alterações, reinicie o Apache.